# How to perform mean subtraction and normalization with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

On http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/ it is mentioned that for convolutional neural networks it is preferred to preprocess data using mean subtraction and normalization techniques.

I was just wondering how would it be best approached using Tensorflow.

Mean substraction

```
X -= np.mean(X)
```

Normalization

```
X /= np.std(X, axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for

1. [`tf.image.per_image_whitening(image)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/image.html#per_image_whitening) if you use Tensorflow version < r0.12
2. [`tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) otherwise.

> Linearly scales image to have zero mean and unit norm.
>
> This op computes (x - mean) / adjusted_stddev, where mean is the average of all values in image, and adjusted_stddev = max(stddev, 1.0/sqrt(image.NumElements())).

Comment: Is the mean per-channel or over all the channels? (same for stddev)

Comment: Over all channels

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the source code for [feature columns](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py) I noticed for real_valued_column types there is a keyword argument normalizer that can take as an argument a default normalization function to apply to each element of the tensor:

```
real_valued_column("col_name", normalizer = lambda x: (x-X.mean())/X.std())
```

Where X is your data. I think the advantage here is the normalization can be applied in the course of a tensor flow graph on a purpose built machine. Also the normalization function can be easily customized.

Answer (score 1):

Best technique is to use `tf.image.per_image_standardization`. 
Read the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization
for more information.